# jsTree context menu not showing with position of Relative in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jstree, jstree-search

Any idea why having the attribute  position: relative; in the CSS of my parent div prevent the context menu of the jsTree from showing. I finally discovered why my context menu in jsTree 3.2 was not showing and its because of this attribute. Full CSS below.

```
#content {
  background: #FFF;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 800px;
  z-index: 18;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 240px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was with the z-index. Needs to be hiugher. Used  .vakata-context { z-index: somethinghigher; }